# I need some help for my project

Tags: transistors, relay, integrated-circuit

I need a favor

I was trying to recreate this circuit but apparently for some reason, it doesn't work. The idea behind this project is that when the user makes a phone call from his phone to the phone, which is attached to the circuit, the load gets activated. Similarly, to turn off the load, the user need to again make a phone call.

In the diagram, the LED in the phone's keypad is attached to the circuit. (I stated this because I don't think it's clear from the diagram)

Can you guys please tell me if the circuit is correct or not and if not, can you please provide me with the correct circuit diagram? And please try to make it as similar to the previous circuit i.e., similar type of components.

Thankyou.
[image: diagram]

Comment: Hi! This is not really a schematic, but a "cartoon"; I don't have the time to look up what the different pins on the CD4017 do, and none of the pins on the white boxes (relays?!) are labeled, so we can't know what they do. Please convert your cartoon to a proper electronic schematic. Also, quite certain a logic IC like the CD4017 is not meant to drive a relay

Comment: Aryan - Welcome :-) For project / homework-type questions like this, you need to show your own effort *first*. Please click the [Edit] link below your question & add more details e.g. you said "it doesn't work", so explain what troubleshooting you have done; explain how you believe the circuit could work and any problems that you see (so we don't waste time telling you what you already know); do you really intend to build this and how would you connect internally to the phone? Please ask a specific question - so far it sounds like you want us to do your project, but it's *your* project! Thanks

Comment: @Aryan:  Where did you find this circuit?  The chances are very good that the original source has some explanation of how it is intended to work.  I don't think that it is intended to connect to the keypad.  It has to be connected to some something that reacts when it receives a call.  The keypads don't normally do that.

Comment: Have a look at sim800, sim900, these are mobile phone boards that are very small and cost $5 or $50. You can program them to do all sorts of things so you are not just turning it on or off but various other things.
With alot of the project people have already made it and you just download the program off the internet. A lot of the work is done for you. I have not answered your question so much but as to point you in a direction for improvement and i hope i spark your interest even further in these project

Comment: While you're editing can you improve the title of your question so that a reader knows what the question is *about*. "I need some help for my project" does not tell us the nature of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you ought ought to draw schematics with logic symbols not photos, but I understand your concept. But if you do not specify currents for each, you can run into problems like NPN Ib, coil current and power relay contact derating for a large AC motor.

- You show a phone trigger for a relay to drive a Johnson counter after so many pulses to drive motor power relay. The 9V battery and 5V relay are redundant and cause for concerns. ( Delete these)
- The phone switch must have a known Vout and Rout to drive the NPN without excess current as no Rs is shown to base. The collector is sufficient to drive the 4017 Clk but the Cap is too big (presumable chosen to debounce redundant 5V relay contacts.
- Verify your voltage and thus implied currents at each stage using LowV from phone to 12V for 4017.
- 4017 is about 300 ohms output R +1k may not be enough to drive 12 coil current and need to be reduced to 300 Ohms if 12V coil is >1V on collector coil V- gnd side.

All wires must be twisted pairs and orthogonal to motor current and relay AC power to prevent crosstalk glitches.

### The Biggest error is phone gnd is not tied to 12V gnd. But follow above advice too.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things making no sense:

1. You dont handle reset pin of 4017 after every call to toggle load state.
2. I dont think the driving CLK input from relay is necessary, then the 10u cap is no needed.
3. Base of Transistor connected to phone has no resistor.
4. Enable pin must be grounded to 4017 start work.

It needs complete rebuild.